# Javascript grab a group of class names and add them as IDs

Tags: javascript

Is there a way with Javascript to store all the class names inside #links into an array and use a loop to assign each  an ID of that class?

Below would be before

```
<div id="links">
    <a href="/somelink" class="aj51">some link</a>
    <a href="/somelink" class="aj53">some link</a>
    <a href="/somelink" class="aj52">some link</a>
    <a href="/somelink" class="aj54">some link</a>
</div>
```

after javascript

```
<div id="links">
    <a href="/somelink" class="aj51" id="aj51">some link</a>
    <a href="/somelink" class="aj53" id="aj53">some link</a>
    <a href="/somelink" class="aj52" id="aj52">some link</a>
    <a href="/somelink" class="aj54" id="aj54">some link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Absolutely. What have you tried?

Comment: Do you need an array for something, or did you just assume you needed an array to do this (you don't) ?

Comment: Given that each element has a unique class-name (though what happens if there are multiple classes on an element?) this looks like you have a server-side script generating the content: why not amend that script to generate `id`s instead of `class`-es?

Comment: Untested:  `$('#links').children('a').each(function(){$(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('class'));})`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/yLkpa34n/

Comment: That said, @DavidThomas is right that you should probably fix this problem server-side.

Comment: @emodendroket - note that there's no jQuery tag on the question.

Comment: @j08691 Well if I were going to take the time to do it carefully and nicely I wouldn't have posted it as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two plain-vanilla ways to do it with JavaScript (no jQuery). Of course this assumes that your only have the one class per element.

```
var elem = document.getElementById('links');
for (var i = 0; i < elem.getElementsByTagName('a').length; i++) {
    elem.getElementsByTagName('a')[i].setAttribute('id',elem.getElementsByTagName('a')[i].className)
}
```

or

```
var links = document.getElementById('links').getElementsByTagName('a');
Array.prototype.map.call(links, function (el) {
    el.setAttribute('id',el.className)
});
```